# EF core one to many relationship with existing data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have two tables called Services and Vendor. Record in service table are already inserted. And when a new vendor is created it can provide 1 or more service from exiting table.

This how the service class looks like

```
public class Service
    {    
        public  int Id { get; set; }
        public  string ServiceName { get; set; }
    }
```

here is how vendor class looks like

```
 public class Vendor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Pin { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumbers { get; set; }
        public string MailId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Service> ServicesProviede {get;set;}
    }
```

and vendorandservice class looks like

```
 public class VendorAndServices
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int VendorID { get; set; }
            public virtual Vendor VendorDetails { get; set; }

            public int ServiceId { get; set; }
            public virtual Service ServiceDetails { get; set; }
        }
```

i have tried various example on google but the problem in one to many relation every time i add a new Vendor it insert a record in SErvices table too.

Comment: Correct, your code is working like that because your object declaration is written that way. You will need to review foreign key relationships. You need to setup your objects to not create a new service but to point to a current service with your foreign key relationship and pull it from the services table. 

Here's a post from the Microsoft documents that explains it further: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key
I just saw your update - but the code in your vendor class isn't setup properly.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I was trying out few things. It seems removing the virtual fields from VendorAndServices did the trick.